# How to add .Net framework to Visual Studio preview 2019 project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have downloaded and  installed Visual studio .Net Framework 4.8 .
But ,How to add this .Net Framework in Visual studio 2019 Project  .

Comment: 2019 preview? The trial and free (with usage restrictions for alrge companies) released version are released for more than 6 months - how che you STILL use 2019 preview?

Comment: In Visual Studio, right click on the project -> properties -> application -> Target Framework

Answer (score 1):

Open the *Project* menu and select *Properties* (this menu entry should have a project name in it).  In the *Application* tab of the Properties window, choose your desired framework from the *Target framework* dropdown.

Comment: Not sure that works on a PREVIEW version of 2019. That one is old and was never updated. What for - the released version is out ages.

Comment: These instructions should work for any relatively recent version of Visual Studio (at least 2015 upwards).

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Enterprise 16.4.3
But still same issue. Nuget package Microsoft.Graph.Auth not getting Installed.

Comment: That's a different problem than the one you described in your question.

Answer (score -2):

You do not. Simple.

You claim (title) to use 2019 preview.

That is ANCIENT - like seriously. The trial and free to download pro version are available for a long time and support for more modern technologies got added there over time.

Download, keep updated and it is just there.

We are now in version 16.4 and a LOT of significant updates where pushed out over time.

Comment: I have installed Visual studio Community 16.4.3 now,but still having same issue.

Comment: Did you add the 4.8 sdk and targeting as per installer? Once those are installed, you can select 4.8 in the properties dropdown.

Comment: Yes, i am using Version 16.5.0 Preview and .net Framework 4.8 is selected ,but then also i am neither getting search result for Microsoft.Graph.Auth in Nuget package manager nor  getting installed using PM console .    
  Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).                                          and the command was:   Install-Package Microsoft.Graph.Auth -Version 1.0.0-preview.3

Comment: I add the nuget package successfully. I suggest you could add it manually. Please right click reference->manage nuget package->Tick to include pre-release->click install. Finally, you can install it successfully.

Comment: I would like to note that this is wrong. The preview versions of Visual Studio are used for the development of new features. 2019 preview is currently at version 16.10.0 Preview 4.0 while community is at 16.9.6.